# Why can't I centre text using margin: auto

Tags: html, css

I know there seem to be a lot of questions like this, but I can't find one that matches my problem.

Even the [w3schools example for centering text](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container) doesn't centre the text, (in Chrome Version 88.0.4324.104 (Official Build) (64-bit) and in Edge Version 88.0.705.50 (Official build) (64-bit)), even on the w3schools website itself. The text stays ranged left.

The code from the site is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Center Align Elements</h2>
<p>To horizontally center a block element (like div), use margin: auto;</p>

<div class="center">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So how *do* I centre text, if I can't even get the w3schools example to work?

Thanks.

Comment: `text-align` centers the content of an element, in your case you are centering the element, not its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: auto` centers the position of a *block* element.  That div is being centered - but that only centers the box itself, not the text within the box.

`text-align: center` centers text (and other inline elements) within its container.

Comment: D'oh! I was looking at the centering of the wrong thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apply on p tag style ="margin:auto ; width: fit-content;"